# Overriding Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page not working

Tags: magento-1.8, cms, overrides

I am trying to create my own module to `override / extend` `Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page`.

This is what I have so far

**1)** Enable the module by creating `/app/etc/modules/Namespace_ModuleName.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_ModuleName>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Namespace_ModuleName>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**2)** Set up the config `/app/code/local/Namespace/ModuleName/etc/config.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> 
 <config>  
  <global>  
     <models>  
        <page_resource>
            <rewrite>
              <page>Namespace_ModuleName_Model_Resource_Page</page>
            </rewrite>
        </page_resource>
    </models>  
 </global>   
</config>
```

**3)** Set up the new model - /`app/code/local/Namespace/ModuleName/Model/Resource/Page.php`

```
class Namespace_ModuleName_Model_Resource_Page extends Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page
{
    protected function _getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object)
    {
        echo 'test';
        exit;
    }
}
```

However when I load a cms page nothing happens but I can see whats wrong. Can anyone advise please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue at wrong calling for resource type at config.xml

it should be  `cms_resource`  from `page_resource`.

As per as ,magento  `cms_resource` resource type class is `Mage_Cms_Model_Resource`

**See  at config.xml of Mage_Cms Module:**

```
 <cms_resource>
                <class>Mage_Cms_Model_Resource</class>
```

Comment: good catch +1 from me@Amit bera